# Finding a Checkbox within Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I hope someone is able to help me with my WebForms issue.

I have a list displayed on a web page using a `Gridview` one of the columns in the grid view has a checkbox.  Adding a checkbox to the gridview isn't the issue I've done that, my problem is I'm unable to read whether the checkbox is checked or not.  When looping through the grid row by row, I specify the cell with the checkbox in and all it returns is `&nbsp;`.

Here is a sample of the code I used to insert the checkbox.

```
 CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
                chk.EnableViewState = true;
                chk.Enabled = true;
                chk.Checked = true;
                chk.ID = "chkb";

                e.Row.Cells[DATA_TABLE_GRID_VIEW_COLUMN_CLOSE].Controls.Add(chk);
```

This is done in the `_RowDataBound` method for the grid (if that makes a difference).

I've tried a couple of different ways for grabbing the value neither have provided me with the result I'm looking for.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in theGrid.Rows)
{
    var val = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridViewMeter_ctl03_chkb");
}
```

In this instance I hard coded an ID for testing purposes, I checked first that the ID exists on the page. 
Here is an example of the HTML that is generated for the grid view.

```
<td>
<span>
    <input id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridViewMeter_ctl03_chkb" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridViewMeter$ctl03$chkb" checked="checked">
</span>
```

I've also tried checking the cell directly for controls and it returns nothing

```
row.Cells[36].Controls.Count
```

Is there anything else  I can try or do to get the value of the checkbox.

Comment: You should not use the generated Id. Use the one you add in code "chkb". But it is strange that you cant find it over the Cell, are you sure it is the right cell.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I don't fully understand the gridviews but it gives each cell in the row a unique id and appends the id I set to the end.  Also I've checked and double checked it is the right cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found a solution to my problem.**

Originally I was adding the checkboxes to the gridview after the grid has been created using the `_RowDataBound` and for whatever reason the checkbox wasn't been detected as a control hence the `.FindControl()` not working.

So when creating the GridView instead of `.Columns.Add("ColumnName")` I set the column as `type bool` `.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Closed", typeof(bool)));`

Then handled the checkbox properties in the `_RowDataBound`

Doing it this way I'm now able to find the Checkbox control uses `.FindControl()`.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried what you need and here is a possible solution.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Student> lista = new List<Student>();
        lista.Add(new Student() { Id = 1, Name = "Nesta" });
        lista.Add(new Student() { Id = 2, Name = "Pirlo" });
        lista.Add(new Student() { Id = 3, Name = "Maldini" });

        GridTest.DataSource = lista;
        GridTest.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridTest_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        chk.EnableViewState = true;
        chk.Enabled = true;
        chk.Checked = true;
        chk.Text = "Test";
        chk.ID = "chkb";

        e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(chk);
    }

    protected void ClickIt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridTest.Rows)
        {
            var val = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkb");
            var name = val.Text;
            var boolvalue = val.Checked;
        }
    }
```

And the HTML side is simple:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridTest" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridTest_RowDataBound" >
<Columns>
</Columns></asp:GridView><asp:Button ID="ClickIt" runat="server" Text="Press" OnClick="ClickIt_Click" />
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This looks great plus looking at it, it should work however for whatever reason this doesn't work with the code that I'm working with :(

Comment: @Richard Can you please add more code then. Probably something is overriding it on load or so. And in which event is your foreach